# Trying to make loop for a function that stops after the result is lower than a certain value

Tags: python, function, for-loop, range

I'm taking a beginner python class and part of an exercise we were given was this:

> The point x with the property x= sin(x)−ax+ 30 is called a fixed point of the  function f(x) = sin(x)−ax+ 30. It can be computed with the so-called fixed point iteration: x(i+1)= sin(x(i))−ax(i)+ 30, where the superscript (i) denotes an iteration counter. Here you find a piece of Python code which performs the first 200 steps of this

```
x=0.5
a=0.5
for i in range(200):
  x = sin(x) - a*x + 30
print('The result after {num} iterations is {res}.'.format(num=i, res=x))
```

> Modify the code in such a way that it stops iterating as soon as |x(i+1)−x(i)| < 10−8. Furthermore it should print a little message if this condition was not met within 200 iteration steps. Test your code with a= 0.5 and a= 8

I've tried to do this but am not getting anywhere with it. This is what I have so far, any help would be much appreciated.

```
x = 0.5
a = 8
iterations = 0

for i in range(y):
    x = sin(x) - a*x + 30
    if abs(x**(i+1) - x**i) < 1.e-8:
        break
    elif i > 200:
        iterations += 1

print('The result after {num} iterations is {res}.'.format(num=i, res=x))

if iterations > 0:
    print('The condition was not met within 200 iteration steps.')
```

Comment: What errors do you get?  Also, I suspect that the test condition is not typed correctly.  Finding 10-8 is pretty easy so it's probably something else.

Comment: This is what I get when running it:
`The result after 999 iterations is nan.

The condition was not met within 200 iteration steps.

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

  if abs(x**(i+1) - x**i) < 1.e-8:

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

  if abs(x**(i+1) - x**i) < 1.e-8:

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

  x = sin(x) - a*x + 30

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sin

  x = sin(x) - a*x + 30`

Comment: Your use of the exponentiation operator `**` is incorrect.  The problem statement wants you to look at successive iterations.  So `x(i+1)` is the value of `x` that comes after `x(i)`.  You need to save the previous value, compute the new value, then take `abs(x_new - x_old)`.  Don't use `**`, that makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks, so instead of `(x**(i+1) - x**i)` I'd put `(x(i+1) - x(i))` then?

Comment: Well that's idea, but you can't just write `x(i+1)` and `x(i)` obviously.  One more time:  You need to save the previous value, in a variable.

Comment: When you say to save the previous value, are you meaning to store previous result of  `x = sin(x) - a*x + 30` as a different variable and then substitute it for the x values in `(x(i+1) - x(i))`? Would I have to have the variable stored outside of the loop or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what happens during the iteration, I advise adding `print(i, x)` to the loop in either the original code (after being corrected with the needed indent) or your code.  You can remove it before submitting.

The original and your code lack `from math import sin`.  Code posted should be ready to run, including needed imports.

Your posted code neglects to define `y=200`, but there is no need to add that for the problem as specified.   In any case, `for i in range(y)` will give i the values 0, 1, ..., 199.  Your condition `i > 200` will never be true.  The easiest way to do something if the loop does not break is to use an `else:` clause.  Or you can replace `iterations` with the more descripting `failure` and correct your condition.

Combined with Tom K's comment, possible code that works is

```
from math import sin

x = 0.5
a = 0.5
for i in range(200):
    x1 = sin(x) - a*x + 30
    print(i, x)  # remove before submitting
    if abs(x1 - x) < 1.e-8:
        break
    x = x1
else:
    print('The condition was not met within 200 iteration steps.')

print('The result after {num} iterations is {res}.'.format(num=i, res=x))
```

This prints for a = .5 and 8:

```
The result after 59 iterations is 20.649274368307022.

The condition was not met within 200 iteration steps.
The result after 199 iterations is -1.1949487767945635e+181.
```