# How to write mathematical sequences in python

Tags: python, math, sequences

I'm completely stuck on a task in one of the exercises we've been given however and was hoping someone could help me with it.

The following is the actual task:

> Consider the sequence: **x(n+1)= 0.2x(n)−α(x(n)^2−5)** with **x(0)=
>   1** for **α** successively equal to **-0.5, +0.5, -0.25, +0.25**.
>
> - Check the convergence; if the sequence converges, print the message *Sequence converged to x= (the value you got)* otherwise print *No convergence detected*
> - Check whether there are negative elements in the sequence
>
> (Hint: If **|xn−xn−1| < 10−9** consider a sequence to be convergent)

I'm not sure how to do sequences in python though and haven't found anything that explains how via googling so have been unsuccessful in trying to do it so far. After numerous attempts, I'm completely stuck.

This is the code I've done:

```
conv = [-0.5, 0.5, -0.25, 0.25]
b=0
a=conv[b]
c=0

for x in conv:
    x1=0.2*x-a*((x**2)-5)
    if abs(x1 - x) < 1.e-9:
        c += 1        
    x = x1
    b += 1

if c > 0:
    print('Sequence converged to x=' + x) 

if c === 0: 
    print('No converge detected')
```

Comment: this is (hopefully) an assignment to teach you about **generators** (giving you a term to google) However, you'll have to learn Python basics first. There's a lot of things that point out you haven't understood how Python functions look like, and you might want to start with that.

Comment: Should the α values be repeated again and again (cycled)? In this case it wouldn't be possible to detect a non-convergence because the sequence never ends and therefore it is always possible that convergence happens yet.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I doubt it, there's no need for generators.

Comment: @AlexHall For the cycling of alphas, that would be handy (pretty sure `itertools` would have one covered, but what would be the point of this, then?)

Comment: I assume the question is asking "does it converge for a = 0.25? does it converge for a = 0.5? etc" but I may be wrong. I'm not sure what the asker meant by "successively", I think it's probably just a mistake.

Comment: @AlexHall Yeah, the successively confuses me as well.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'll go look up generators, thanks. We haven't been issued any textbooks yet so I'm just having to go off what I find online hence the terrible (and probably error ridden) code

Comment: @Charon I think alex might be right, you shouldn't be looking into generatros right now. Instead, learn python from python.org, and start from 0. There's a lot of *good* material out there, you just seem to have found bad stuff.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yeah, I'm trying to do that alongside but my class is pretty fast-paced and I can't fail the assessments so unfortunately I have to try and do them even though I barely understand it. Do you have any sites other than python.org you'd recommend for learning material?

Comment: that is a recipe to actually fail. Python is a relatively easy and intuitive language. I've learnt how to write python functions within the first 10 minutes of using it. In other words, you asking the question here has taken about as long as it would have taken you to start reading.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You're probably right.  How long do you think it would take to bring myself up to scratch for my class material if I go back and try starting from the very basics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure is called 'fixed-point iteration'.  The question is similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116080/trying-to-make-loop-for-a-function-that-stops-after-the-result-is-lower-than-a-c), asked yesterday (and likely others).

The sequence definition shows `a` as a constant.  Indeed, letting a vary for a given sequence in the way indicated makes no sense as it would guarantee non-convergence.  The instructor's notation is sloppy, but I am sure that the intent is for students to run 4 iterations, one for each value of `a1`.  (I say this also because I know what fixed-point iteration behaviors are illustrated by the particular choices for `a`.)

The code below mixes my answer from the link above with the update code from this question.  N is chosen as large enough for this problem (I started larger).  Charon, I leave it to you to use the results to answer the questions posed by the instructor.

```
for a in [-0.5, 0.5, -0.25, 0.25]:
    x = 1.0
    n = 30
    for i in range(n):
        x1 = 0.2*x - a*(x**2 - 5)
        print(i, x)  # remove before submitting
        if abs(x1 - x) < 1.e-9:
            print('a = {a}, n = {i}, result is {x}.'.format(a=a, i=i, x=x))
            break
        x = x1
    else:
        print('No convergence within {n} iterations.'.format(n=n))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the values in your "conv" list, assigning them to a, like "for a in conv:". Each iteration of the loop is a sequence as defined by a different "a" value. Then inside that loop, another loop like:

```
for a in conv:
    convergence_determined = False
    n = 0
    x = 1    # this is x(0) for this sequence
    while not convergence_determined:
        prev_x = x
        n = n += 1
        next_x = 0.2 * x - a * (x * x - 5)
        x = next_x
        if abs(x - prev_x) < 1.e-9:
            convergence_determined = True
            print('for a = ' + str(a) + ', converged to ' + str(x))
            break
        # you will need some scheme to identify non-convergence
```

This is not tested code, just to give you an idea of how to proceed.